# Virtual Keyboard doesn't appear in an Android Hybrid Application but does appear in the web browser, on the same phone

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I have a `<textarea>` type of text field in a web application from my Android mobile.

When I try to access the website with a browser, the virtual keyboard appears as expected.
When I try the same thing in an Android application, for the same page, it doesn't work, the virtual keyboard doesn't appear.

Context :

- PhoneGap 0.9.6 is used to help generate application
- a fork a jQTouch is used for the U.I.

The same application works on an iPhone 4.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts and ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to simplify the use of PhoneGap.
It worked on the embedded application but not on the website.